# How to create recursive hbs code in ember?

Tags: recursion, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a hbs file that contains following

```
//some ohter code
-------------------------------------
    {{#each items}}
            <li>
                {{name}}
                {{#if items}}
                    <ul>
                        //partial should go here
                    </ul>
                {{/if}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
---------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to use `same section` recursively replacing `//partial should go here`. How can I do that? Appreciate any help

Comment: sounds like you want to place that in a component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember used to have `parital`, `render` and `include` template tags, which they are trying to get rid of however.
Now, probably the best way is to make use of components. If you are on ember-cli, just open your terminal and type `ember g component my-include`. It generates a *.js and a *.hbs file (naming depending on whether you are using pods or not).
Then you put the template code you want to use multiple times in the newly created *.hbs file, and then in your existing template code:

```
{{#if items}}
      <ul>
        {{my-include}}
      </ul>
{{/if}}
```

You might want to take a look at: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/components/defining-a-component/ for more information

You can also look at this [sample working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a6b417b37597e91be5b42316819c551f?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

Comment: I aggree with you. So I've just added a twiddle to your post.